# add Google Calendar notifications for entire subscribed calendar

Tags: google-calendar

Google Calendar lets you add public calendars to your Google Calendar. For example, I have subscribed to the calendar for an NFL football team I am interested in, so now all of their games show up in my Google Calendar.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get notifications for this calendar. With my own calendar if I click on it, there is a section in Settings called Event Notifications where I can choose default notification settings (the default if you don't change it is a notification 2 hours before and an email 2 hours before). There is nothing like this for the public calendars.

Are there any hacks to do something similar for these public calendars? I am a bit surprised they don't provide this functionality.